# Using a class from imported package in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Let's say I have package A, and inside package A I would like to pass param to class B in order to create an object.

I've already confirmed that to create an object of class B, all I need to do is to pass in param to class B, like so: classB(param)

In rpy2, would I do object = packageA.classB(param)? Is this the right syntax? I can't find the specification in the doc.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is very unclear question. Please, add more information and also, your codes.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if I can share code, but please let me know what's unclear/confusing!